# Unity FPS Drop on Android Low end devices

Tags: unity, android, lag

I have stumbled upon an issue that is now taking a lot more time than I assumed. I have a game that has a lagging issue and I have tried almost all techniques that I could remember to fix that but now I am in desperate need of advice.
I am on **Unity 2019.4.14f1 (URP)**

I have done the following:

1. Turned off everything including UI and still CPU around 40ms and 25fps on **Samsung Galaxy S6**
2. Optimized Memory though textures compression of RGBA Crunched ETC2 or RGB Crunched ETC as needed.
3. Added target framerate = 60 as without this Semaphore.WaitForSignal took a lot more CPU ms and was resulting in even worst FPS even in an empty scene.
4. Turned off vSync
5. Turned off all sort of lights in the game
6. Tried turning off scriptable render features just to be sure they are not culprits.

Here are the setting screenshots:

[image: Quality Setting]

[image: URP-renderer]

[image: URP]

Here are profiling screenshots of gameplay without turning off everything.

[image: FrameA]

[image: FrameB]

Here are the screenshots when everything including Ui, 3D Env/Char, and lights are turned off.

[image: FrameA]

[image: FrameB]

Comment: Can you tell us what the "...iceVK.Present" line in the Render Thread section says, in full? I'm not getting hits for that term, though [I do find potentially related advice for Device.Present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44624524/3064164)...

Comment: It's saying GfxDeviceVK.Present(40.95ms).

Comment: About the other thread that you recommended I saw and I have ensured following:
1. No Image Effects on Camera (Turned off Post-processing)
2. No Shadows
3. V Sync Off
4. Auto-Graphics is off with Vulkan and OpenGLES3 and Require ES3.2 ticked
5. UI off so there is no Image with Alpha
6. Custom Shaders did exist but as everything is turned off so I don't think they are contributing.

Comment: What about that Kawase Blur I see in your renderer configuration?

Comment: Yes I used this for Ui Blur Effect I did try to remove and see the impact but it didn't help for FPS although let me try removing that again.

Comment: So I found the culprit that I was missing as Kawase Blur wasn't creating an issue. 
There was another camera that was not being rendered but it had post-processing turned on and anti-aliasing set to fast approximate. When I turned off that gameobject FPS jumped back to around 55FPS and after 3 mins of idle-ness it got back to around 25 - 30 FPS which was caused by heatup issue because the device was quite hot after 3 mins.

Comment: Want to share that as an Answer below?

Comment: Shared my steps. Hopefully, it will help someone out there too. Thank you for your support and direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of digging finally achieved 60 FPS on Samsung Galaxy S6 with the following steps:

1. Included Graphics APIs OpenGLES2
2. Texture streaming and generated mipmaps and mipmap streaming
3. Incremental GC
4. C++ Compiler set to Master (was previously set to Debug)
5. Depth Texture off in URP

Comment: Thanks, bro.. this fixed my issue as well with URP. BTW I did not do 2,3,4 things. anyway. thanks, bud.

Comment: Since [Galaxy S6 runs OpenGLES3.1 and even 3.2](https://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx40&D=Samsung+Galaxy+S6+%28SM-G920x%2C+SC-05G%2C+SM-S907%29&testgroup=info), why did the step "1. Included Graphics APIs OpenGLES2" benefit the performance ?